# keras and tensorflow installation problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tensorflow, keras

For some reason I downgrade the tensorflow 2.2.0 with 1.5.0 on windows machine 64 bit with python 3.6 (by uninstalling tensorflow 2.2.0 and then installing tensorflow 1.5.0). Now I want to use the latest version of tensorflow and I did the same work and after uninstalling, I installed the tensorflow 2.2.0 again, but I get below error:

```
File "C:\Users\AI_team\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import RandomRotation
  File "C:\Users\AI_team\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\AI_team\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "C:\Users\AI_team\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\framework_lib.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import Graph
  File "C:\Users\AI_team\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 30, in <module>
    from six.moves import xrange  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
ImportError: cannot import name 'xrange'
```

I just used keras in my code, but tensorflow as the backbone of keras send this error.
How can I fix it?

Comment: `xraneg` is coming from python2. Check your python version used while building tensorflow wheel.

Comment: I'm sure that my python version is 3.6.8